# ember hash urls in google

Tags: ember.js

I am concerned about page ranking on google with the following situation:

I am looking to convert my existing site with 150k+ unique page results to a ember app, off the route. so currently its something like  domain.com/model/id - With ember and hash change - it will be /#/model/id. I really want history state but lack of IE support doesn't leave that as a option. So my Sitemap for google has lots and lots of great results using the old model/id. On the rails side I will test browser for compatibility, before either rendering the JS rich app or the plain HTML / CSS. Does anyone have good SEO suggestions with my current schema for success.

Linked below is my schema and looking at the options - 
http://static.allplaces.net/images/EmberTF.pdf
History state is awesome but it looks like support is only around 60% of browsers.
http://caniuse.com/history

Thanks guys for the suggestions, the google guide is similar to what I'm going to try. I will roll it out to 1 client this month, and see what webmasters and analytics show.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

here is everything you need to have your hash links be seo friendly: https://developers.google.com/webmasters/ajax-crawling/

basically You write Your whole app with hashlinks, but You have to add "!" to them, so You have #!/model/id. Next You must have all pages somewhere generated and if google asks for them, return "plain html" as described here:  https://developers.google.com/webmasters/ajax-crawling/docs/getting-started

use google webmaster tools to check if Your site is crawlable.

Comment: and here is example of such wabpage (not mine): http://www.boletus-app.com/ - it's written in backbone, but similiar techniques can be used in ember, and it's all crawled by google.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure if you're aware that you can configure Ember to use the browser history for the location API and keep using your pages the way they are reference now. All you need to do is configure the Route's location property

```
App.Router.reopen({
  location: 'history'
});
```

See more details about specifying the location api [here](http://emberjs.com/guides/routing/specifying-the-location-api/)

Comment: Note that even if you do this, your site will still not be properly crawled without further action on your part. See https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/174992#