# Running Ember only on subroute

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ember.js

On my ember application, I don't want it hooked into the root url(s) instead on a subpath controller. How do I do this? 
For example:   / <- home page & /contact <- static (non JS app - Just render though Rails) 
But I want   /my_awesome_JS_app && /my_awesome_js_app/1   to have ember running on that.

The final goal will be to have when a request comes in to /my_awesome_app/1234  -> It hits the rails application Which checks server side for browser compatibility. After that if its compatible it will load in the ember application  -

So right now with Ember hitting - root - and rails rendering off and ignoring the /#/  and only showing - /  of the hash. I'm a bit stumped and what would be a good solution for this issue. 
This would be a part 2 to my original question - 
[ember hash urls in google](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14616783/ember-hash-urls-in-google)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can require code, that relates to Ember, only in your `/my_awesome_js_app` urls. To do this, you can place a specific `javascript_include_tag 'ember_app'` into view, which loads in this url. And in file `app/assets/javascripts/ember_app.js` you should have initialization code for ember. For example, in my case this file looks like:

```
#= require handlebars
#= require ember
#= require ember-data
#= require_self
#= require store
#= require_tree ./models
#= require_tree ./controllers
#= require_tree ./views
#= require_tree ./helpers
#= require_tree ./templates
#= require_tree ./routes

window.App = Ember.Application.create
  rootElement: '#ember'
```

Don't forget, that you should not require this file in `application.js` (be aware of `require_tree .`).

Comment: Thanks Mikhail. That helped me a lot get this up and running.